# Do I need to do two EF Includes if second include was referenced in first include?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have this line of code that selects a workflow status and then gets the next workflow statuses mapped to it.

```
status = db.WorkflowStatuses
    .Include(x => x.CurrentMappings.Where(y => y.IsActive && y.NextWorkflowStatus.IsActive))
    .Include(x => x.CurrentMappings.Select(y => y.NextWorkflowStatus).Where(y => y.IsActive))
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
```

My question is do I need the second `Include` since I referenced NextWorkflowStatus in the first `Include`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Include` represents eager loading and eager loading in EF doesn't support filtering or ordering so your code will not work at all. You cannot use `Where` inside include call.